# how to store value in session in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to hold input data in session in the view and later send it to the controller. how can I do that?
I have two textboxes in view and I want to store those data in session .then post it with ajax to the controller.
how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to hold input data in session in the view and later send it to the controller. how can I do that? I have two textboxes in view and I want to store those data in session .then post it with ajax to the controller. how can I achieve that?

Please note you can not directly set Session variable on client side JavaScript.

For more information about Session state and accessing Session values in ASP.NET Core, please check the following doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-and-get-session-values

Besides, `sessionStorage` could help maintain a separate storage area for each given origin that's available for the duration of the page session. You can try to store input data in `sessionStorage` while textboxes/input fields' change event is triggered, so that you can get stored data from `sessionStorage` and make AJAX request with data to your controller action.

For more information about `sessionStorage`, please check:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net Controller is backside, so you want to store data fronside in for example js?

In the browser with js and other frontside frameworks you can store data literally ANYWHERE, try **window.localStorage**, **window.sessionStorage** or in a SPA app try a global variable.

I would like to see an answer for backside in asp.net session.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).